# Experience Manager automatic publishing failing in Web 8.5

Tags: publishing, web8.5, experience-manager

I'm working on a Web 8.5 implementation where the client is using legacy publishing with publishing targets. They leverage bundle workflow for managing the passing back & forth of all the content, and Experience Manager for building out their pages.

Up until recently, this process was working great - however, we've run into an issue where the item being edited is NOT being automatically published when the user clicks "Finish Editing". The save goes through successfully, but no items are published.

A bit of information about our setup:

- SDL Web 8.5
- Legacy publishing (no microservices)
- Translation Manager is setup (WorldServer)
- Session preview is disabled

I noticed in the network tab that the call to PublishItems is failing:

```
/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Publishing.svc/PublishItems
```

And it is failing with error:

```
"ExceptionDetail": {
   "HelpLink":null,
   "InnerException":null,
   "Message":"Value cannot be null.\u000d\u000aParameter name: collection",
   "StackTrace": "...."
}
```

Where Tridion is sending the following in the request payload:

```
{"ids":null,"instruction":null}
```

So obviously there's something wrong with the call to publish the items. I'm not really sure where to investigate as the feature seemed to randomly stop working, and does not seem to be related to any extensions we've added.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what we can look into next?

I've tried installing Hotfix XPM_8.5.0.6084 which deals with an issue:

> "Committing" changes made in XPM very slow when there are a large number of bundles and bundle workflow processes.

But no luck, although it did make the "Finish Editing" step complete much faster :) I'm just a bit stumped as to where I should look next as it simply stopped working in our Production environment. Any insights or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder whether the XPM markup is correct on the page or if something else (malformed HTML maybe) is causing problems. Can you check that the XPM markup is 100% correct on the page? Could you maybe create a very simple Page Template with very little HTML markup and the XPM tags to test it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Jonathan. It seems to be more of a system wide issue, as I have been testing across multiple (4-5) page types that we have which I've confirmed have not been updated, and had been working previously. I did try your suggestion of stripping down the HTML to see, but it seems as though the issue still exists. The content is all saved correctly in the CM, it's just the request to publish the item that's failing because no ID is being sent for some reason.

Comment: It it possible your cd_dynamic or cd_link conf has been updated and the url in those files no longer matches the one that the user sees in their browser when they visit the site? If the urls do not match then it is possible that XPM cannot resolve where to publish to.

Comment: It's a great suggestion Nicholas. I checked those configurations and it appears as though they have no changed (unfortunately).

Comment: Any update on this, Josh? Did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: No luck yet. I'm still stumped as to why it would break as we didn't change add any extensions, or change any configurations. Oddly enough, the exist also does not exist in our QA environment. I know it's a bit of an edge case because we're on Web 8.5 using legacy publishing WITHOUT Session Preview, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why it would stop working.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm stumped too :)  Are there any errors in the Console in Chrome Developer Tools? What are the equivalent `{"ids":null,"instruction":null}` values in another environment where this still works?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply Jonathan. I've been doing more investigating; we've noticed when you make a change and click "Finish Editing" the error occurs, but on subsequent clicks of "Finish Editing" (after making a second change) the publish does go through. So it's only happening on the first click of "Finish Editing". Here's the payload when the request is successful: `{"ids":["tcm:27-21411"],"instruction":{"targets":["tcm:0-1-65537"],"activateWorkflow":true,"resolveContentItems":true,"resolveComponentLinks":true}}`.